# Mac ASL: Unable to see my application's log messages

Tags: macos, logging, syslogd, asl

I have just added ASL logging support to my application (a compiled binary) but I cannot see any log entries using Console.app.  I am logging with facility 'com.mydomain.myapp' (that's not the actual value) and have added an entry to `/private/etc/asl.conf` to tell syslogd to 'store' entries at this Facility (with any Level):

```
? [= Facility com.mydomain.myapp] store
```

I HUP'd syslogd with no success so I restarted my MacBook Pro, which also made no difference.

I know my application is logging OK as I have added the option `ASL_OPT_STDERR` when calling `asl_open()` and can see the entries on stderr.  I have also set the filters, using `asl_set_filter()`, to allow the appropriate levels to be sent to the server.

EDIT: I have seen this [article](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg43986.html), which gives an alternative way of setting the 'cutoff' value used by syslogd, however than doesn't work either (tried both temporary and permanent fixes):

> ... the reason you don't see Info or
>   Debug messages is that the   syslogd
>   daemon filters them.  If you want to
>   change the filtering in   syslogd, you
>   can change the startup options in
>   /System/Library/ 
>   LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist
>   (add -c and
>   -7 in the
>   ProgramArguments array).  That makes
>   the   change "permanent" (until you
>   change the plist again).  See the
>   syslogd  (8) man page.
>
> Alternatively, you can make a
>   temporary change to the syslogd
>   database   filter value using the
>   "syslog" command-line utility.
>        sudo syslog -c syslogd -d

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether this app is a shell script or a compiled binary. If a shell script I have always used the logger command to update logs in syslog. If you are using Xcode and building a compiled Cocoa project you might get better assistance posting to StackOverFlow.

Comment: It's a compiled binary (without GUI).  I don't think SO is appropriate and I'm pretty sure it's not a programming error - rather it seems to be a system error.