# MacOS - How to change syslogd's log level for a specific process/program?

Tags: linux, macos, logging, syslog, syslogd

I am new to MacOS and I would like to get a better of view of what's going on with a system process when my computer is starting up. I can see in the log that a process is changing settings, but the log doesn't say how.

I am thinking that by setting the log level to debug, the syslog will capture more information about what the process is doing. If I run `sudo syslog -c SystemUIServer -d` to increase the log level, the setting does not get saved when I reboot my computer.

I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/232677/mac-asl-unable-to-see-my-applications-log-messages) that it is possible to change the setting permanently somewhere in the .plist file for syslogd, but I don't understand how.

Can someone tell me the settings to permanently raise the log level for a specific process to get more information from the log file?

**Edit:**

In the /system/library/launchdaemons directory, I added the code below to a .plist file for one of the system services and **it made my computer unbootable.**

```
<key>WaitForDebugger</key>
<true/>
<key>Debug</key>
<true/>
```

When I got my system running again with a backup of the original .plist file, the console logs showed the process wouldn't load because launchd was waiting for debugger. The Debug logging key seems to be different from running a 'Debugger' program ?? I really don't know. I'm still looking for a solution and would appreciate any advice.